# How to Find CSS Selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am having trouble targeting a specific element. I'm trying to change the background color of a widget. My problem is this widget is used in a few spots on the site, so if I change something via CSS, it changes in all the widgets. I've been trying different selector combos via inspecting the element. I can't quite find the right one. The site is here http://titanpanama.com/newsite/ I'm trying to change the backgound-color of the list items under the heading Specials. I've tried

```
.specials-home .home-estate-widget .post-list li{ background-color:#000; }
```

I've tried adding a class to the container. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: didnt get your question ??..can you elaborate

Comment: Hi, why so complicated, just give id to that <ul> and then change css like this: #your_id li {background: red}

Comment: looks like `.home-estate-widget` is messing it up - not inside `.specials-home` and is an id not a class. I would go with a simple but specific selector, e.g. `.specials-home ul.specials li { background-color: #000; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specifically target the list items in Specials widget, use this:

```
.specials-home ul.post-list li {
  background: #000;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Manoj! This is just what I was looking for.  I just removed  .cat_post_item-1 to change the background color of all items in that sidebar.

Comment: Welcome :) Yes `.cat_post_item-1` was to target a specific element inside special.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div#my_poststypewidget-18 > .specials li {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

It targets all children elements that are li in element with class .specials.

[image]